# Unexpected request GET feature/app/public.html No more request expected $digest already in progress

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

Am writing unit test case for testing `<tabs><pane title="my First tab"></pane></tabs>`
Reference :[Directive tab pane unit tests](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/testing-directives.html)

```
 beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $injector) {
        httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        elm = angular.element(
            '<div>' +
            '<tabs>' +
            '<pane title="First Tab">' +
            'First content is ' +
            '</pane>' +
            '<pane title="Second Tab">' +
            'Second content is ' +
            '</pane>' +
            '</tabs>' +
            '</div>');

        scope = $rootScope;
        $compile(elm)(scope);
        scope.$digest();           
        httpBackend.whenGET('feature/app/public.htm').respond(elm);

     }));


   it('should create clickable titles', function () {
        console.log(elm.find('ul.nav-tabs'));
        var titles = elm.find('ul.nav-tabs li a');

        expect(titles.length).toBe(2);
        expect(titles.eq(0).text()).toBe('First Tab');
        expect(titles.eq(1).text()).toBe('Second Tab');
    });
```

Because  scope.$digest();  was giving the above error I added httpBackend to load the template.But the error still seems to exist.
Please suggest any possible fixes for the above error

Comment: What is the error  you are getting without httpBackend? I don't think you require httpBackend templates are inline

Comment: Unexpected request GET feature/app/public.html No more request expected $digest already in progress.This is the error that I'm getting

Comment: could you remove  scope.$digest();   ? as it is redundant if it said $digest already in progress.

Comment: It's only a guess but try moving the line
`httpBackend.whenGET('feature/app/public.htm').respond(elm);`
before
`$compile(elm)(scope);`

Comment: The error has fixed now.Resolved by creating the directive in my specific module.Previously I was refering from another module.But the second expect statement is failing.ie., expect(titles.eq(0).text()).toBe('First Tab');